# Can't execute a MySQL stored procedure from Java

Tags: java, mysql, stored-procedures, privileges

I am connecting to a MySQL (5.08) database running on a linux machine from a web application running in tomcat.

I get the following exception when I try to execute a stored procedure:

```
com.hp.hpl.chaos.web.exception.DBException: getNextValue for operatorinstance[Additional Information from SQL Exception][SQLErrorCode: 0 SQLState: S1000
    at com.hp.hpl.chaos.web.util.SQLUtil.getNextValue(SQLUtil.java:207)
        ..............

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:910)
at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getCallStmtParameterTypes(DatabaseMetaData.java:1619)
at com.mysql.jdbc.DatabaseMetaData.getProcedureColumns(DatabaseMetaData.java:4034)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.determineParameterTypes(CallableStatement.java:709)
at com.mysql.jdbc.CallableStatement.<init>(CallableStatement.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.parseCallableStatement(Connection.java:4583)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareCall(Connection.java:4657)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.prepareCall(Connection.java:4631)
at com.hp.hpl.chaos.web.util.SQLUtil.getNextValue(SQLUtil.java:196)
... 17 more
```

After installing mysql on the machine. I have given the follwing grant options to root

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

In the java class..

I am connecting to the db as follows:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/test";
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root", "pass");
```

I have also tried the url with the `noAccessToProcedureBodies=true` option included.

Can someone tell me what is wrong here? Is there anything I need to check?

Comment: sorry the grant should read *.* instead of .

Comment: I thinking that MySQL's GRANTs don't always work as you might expect. I've sometimes found that things work if you use specific GRANT permissions rather than *.*

Answer (score 79):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. set the connection's `noAccessToProcedureBodies=true` property

   For example as part of the connection string:

   ```
   jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/test?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true
   ```

   The JDBC driver will then create "INOUT" strings for the arguments without requiring meta data like the exception says.
2. Grant `SELECT` privileges on `mysql.proc` to the database user

   For example in the mysql prompt:

   ```
   GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'user'@'localhost';
   ```

   Of course this would allow the application to read the entire `mysql.proc` table that contains information about *all* stored procedures in *all* databases (including source code).

Comment: This (and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1880461/7708) are examples of what makes me dislike using MySQL.

Comment: @Kush: In my particular experience the Connector/J 5.1.12 seems not aware of the noAccessToProcedureBodies parameter; the latest (currently) 5.1.x version, the 5.1.26 one, is aware of it. Hope this helps.

Comment: First option works for me. I'm using JDBC MySQL connector driver, 5.1.30 version

Comment: Instead of granting on "mysql.proc" why not grant on "schema.proc" where schema is your db schema?

Comment: if you access mysql server from remote host use
GRANT SELECT ON mysql.proc TO 'user'@'%';

Comment: Why is not enough to establish grant all privileges on test.* to user@localhost in order to execute the procedure? The 'all privileges' includes EXECUTE for procedures, right?

Answer (score 3):

Running below queries should fix your issue.

```
GRANT <SELECT, CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, ALL> PRIVILEGES ON mysql.proc TO '<user>'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Answer (score 2):

Following steps worked for me in mysql

Step 1 : add follwong
Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://ipaddress:3306/logparser?noAccessToProcedureBodies = true ",
    "root", "");

Step 2 :
              GRANT ALL ON `logparser`.`proc` TO root@'%'; where logparser is DB name and proc is procedure name.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the definer in the mysql.proc table to your database user.

select * from mysql.proc;

choose the stored proc that has problem and change the definer to 'yourdbuser'@'localhost'.