# Cannot execute a stored procedure (jdbc). 'noAccessToProcedureBodies=true'

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, mysql-connector

We have a java tomcat server on one end, and a mysql on the other. 
We are using mysql-connector-java, tried with versions 5.1.11 and 5.1.22. The mysql server version is 5.5.26

We do not have all the permissions for the mysql.proc table, as it is a security risk to all databases.

I can execute the procedures when I log in mysql with the given username and password, but when used from java (jdbc) it blows up with

```
java.sql.SQLException: User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of actual parameter types.
```

I tried the suggestion mysql has given, used 'noAccessToProcedureBodies=true' in our jdbc connection URL's. Didn't help at all! No difference whatsoever. (Here is an example of jdbc connection string I used: jdbc:mysql://xxxxxx:xxxx/xxxx?noAccessToProcedureBodies=true&useInformationSchema=true )

As I read http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=61203 I saw there is a bug in the connector and I tried using useInformationSchema=true as suggested. Didn't help, and neither did updating the mysql-connector-java, even though the bug is supposed to be fixed.

Has anyone faced this? I guess I am doing something wrong, everyone says it should work but for me it doesnt.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked the database permission to that user? because similar kind of exception I have faced and that got solved by assigning privileges to the db user in database

Comment: We have permissions to execute every function and procedure. I think we don't even have a read permission on mysql.proc and I we won't be allowed to have it.

Comment: This problem has already been answered here: [Can't execute a MySQL stored procedure from Java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986628/cant-execute-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-java

Answer (score 1):

Haven't verified it... just use this: useInformationSchema=true for sql URL. (dont put noAccessToBodies).

Comment: It worked for me! I already used this parameter noAccessToProcedureBodies in another project, but in the current one it didn't work. It was just changing the parameter in the URL that worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have MySQL Server Version : 5.1.52 
My SQL Connector jar : mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar 
Tomcat : 7.0.27.0 
JDK 1.6.0.18

The above problem got solved by adding `noAccessToProcedureBodies=true` and it works for me !

Comment: I also varified using just "useInformationSchema=true" without "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true"  and it did not work for me

Comment: I have been having this problem with ColdFusion10(built on java), where the usual flag of noAccessToProcedureBodies=true used to get us the money shot. Now useInformationSchema=true WITHOUT noAccessTo... in the connection string is working.