# Coldfusion 10 / MySQL 5.5 error on stored procedure (noAccessToProcedureBodies=true)

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

This error popped up today when a CF page attempted to access a stored procedure to get a user record.  Only parameter in is a numeric ID from the session.  This is the error that was thrown:

> User does not have access to metadata required to determine stored
>   procedure parameter types. If rights can not be granted, configure
>   connection with "noAccessToProcedureBodies=true" to have driver
>   generate parameters that represent INOUT strings irregardless of
>   actual parameter types.

I've accessed the same page and it doesn't throw the error at all.  I've done testing by creating a new page and same thing - no error.  The db user has access to stored procedures in CFAdmin and the db user has permissions set correctly as well.  Furthermore when going through the error, the parameter passed in was correct (INT):

> (param 1) = [type='IN', class='java.lang.Integer', value='390790', sqltype='cf_sql_integer']

No other errors were logged around the time of this one, and a driver error like this has me a bit more concerned than one of my normal CF errors that are caught.  This is a fairly busy site and if it was something lasting I'd be swimming in error reports.

> update next day

The db server is at 192.168.100.213 and the web servers are all 192.168.100.xxx.  There are two users configured in MySQL to access the database.  #1 has permissions set to 192.168.100.%.  #2 has the static IP of our office.  Prior to the errors cropping up yesterday there was one user with access of "%" (from any host).  Reverting to that solved the problem but I'm curious as to why now.

Comment: have look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986628/cant-execute-a-mysql-stored-procedure-from-java

Comment: I'm going to edit the original question with more details